# Denoising linear autoencoder learns to output a constant instead of denoising

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, signal-processing, autoencoder

I am trying to create a denoising autoencoder for `1d` cyclic signals like `cos(x)` etc.

The process of creating the dataset is that I pass a list of cyclic functions and for each example generated it rolls random coefficients for each function in the list so every function generated is different yet cyclic. eg - `0.856cos(x) - 1.3cos(0.1x)`

Then I add noise and normalize the signal to be between `[0, 1)`.

Next, I train my autoencoder on it but it learns to output a constant (usually `0.5`). my guess is that it happens because `0.5` is the usual mean value of the normalized functions. But this is not the result im aspiring to get at all.

I am providing the code I wrote for the autoencoder, the data generator and the training loop as well as two pictures depicting the problem im having.

first example:
[image: As you can see the model just learn to output a constant]

second example:
[image]

**Linear autoencoder:**

```
class LinAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, K, B, z_dim, out_channels):
        super(LinAutoencoder, self).__init__()

        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.K = K # number of samples per 2pi interval
        self.B = B # how many intervals
        self.out_channels = out_channels

        encoder_layers = []
        decoder_layers = []

        encoder_layers += [
            nn.Linear(in_channels * K * B, 2*z_dim, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(2*z_dim, z_dim, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(z_dim, z_dim, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU()
        ] 

        decoder_layers += [
            nn.Linear(z_dim, z_dim, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(z_dim, 2*z_dim, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(2*z_dim, out_channels * K * B, bias=True),
            nn.Tanh()
        ]


        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(*encoder_layers)
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(*decoder_layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.shape[0]
        x_flat = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        enc = self.encoder(x_flat)
        dec = self.decoder(enc)
        res = dec.view((batch_size, self.out_channels, self.K * self.B))
        return res
```

**The data generator:**

```
def lincomb_generate_data(batch_size, intervals, sample_length, functions, noise_type="gaussian", **kwargs)->torch.tensor:

    channels = 1
    mul_term = 2 * np.pi / sample_length

    positions = np.arange(0, sample_length * intervals)
    x_axis = positions * mul_term
    X = np.tile(x_axis, (channels, 1))
    y = X

    Y = np.repeat(y[np.newaxis, :], batch_size, axis=0)

    if noise_type == "gaussian":
        # defaults to 0, 0.4
        noise_mean = kwargs.get("noise_mean", 0)
        noise_std  = kwargs.get("noise_std", 0.4)
    
        noise = np.random.normal(noise_mean, noise_std, Y.shape)
    
    if noise_type == "uniform":
        # defaults to 0, 1
        noise_low  = kwargs.get("noise_low", 0)
        noise_high = kwargs.get("noise_high", 1)
    
        noise = np.random.uniform(noise_low, noise_high, Y.shape)


    coef_lo  = -2
    coef_hi  =  2
    coef_mat = np.random.uniform(coef_lo, coef_hi, (batch_size, len(functions))) # creating a matrix of coefficients
    coef_mat = np.where(np.abs(coef_mat) < 10**-1, 0, coef_mat)

    for i in range(batch_size):
    
        curr_res = np.zeros((channels, sample_length * intervals))
        for func_id, function in enumerate(functions):
            curr_func = functions[func_id]
            curr_coef = coef_mat[i][func_id]
            curr_res += curr_coef * curr_func(Y[i, :, :])
        
        Y[i, :, :] = curr_res
    
    clean = Y
    noisy = clean + noise

    # Normalizing
    clean -= clean.min(axis=2, keepdims=2)
    clean /= clean.max(axis=2, keepdims=2) + 1e-5 #avoiding zero division

    noisy -= noisy.min(axis=2, keepdims=2)
    noisy /= noisy.max(axis=2, keepdims=2) + 1e-5 #avoiding zero division

    clean = torch.from_numpy(clean)
    noisy = torch.from_numpy(noisy)

    return x_axis, clean, noisy
```

**Training loop:**

```
functions = [lambda x: np.cos(0.1*x),
             lambda x: np.cos(x),
             lambda x: np.cos(3*x)]

num_epochs = 200

lin_loss_list = []

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

lin_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(lin_model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)

_, val_clean, val_noisy = util.lincomb_generate_data(batch_size, B, K, functions, noise_type="gaussian")

print("STARTED TRAINING")

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # generate data returns the x-axis used for plotting as well as the clean and noisy data
    _, t_clean, t_noisy = util.lincomb_generate_data(batch_size, B, K, functions, noise_type="gaussian")

    # ===================forward=====================
    lin_output = lin_model(t_noisy.float())
    lin_loss = criterion(lin_output.float(), t_clean.float())
    lin_loss_list.append(lin_loss.data)

    # ===================backward====================
    lin_optimizer.zero_grad()
    lin_loss.backward()
    lin_optimizer.step()

    val_lin_loss = F.mse_loss(lin_model(val_noisy.float()), val_clean.float())

print("DONE TRAINING")
```

edit: shared the parameters requested

```
L = 1
K = 512
B = 2

batch_size = 64
z_dim = 64

noise_mean = 0
noise_std  = 0.4
```

Comment: Can you share the parameters(K, B, z_dim etc) used?

Comment: I've tried many values over the course of the last few days, I posted the current ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didnt use `nn.BatchNorm1d` in my model so i guess something wrong happened during training (probably vanishing gradients).